# Regex in sublime text is not efficient

Tags: json, regex, sublimetext3

I want to find and delete 'indicent' object in my json using sublime. here's the regex

```
\s*+,\s*(.)+"\s*indices+"\s*:\s*+(.)\s*\s*(.)+\s*(.)+\s*+]
```

but, it's ran out of stack space. i think that regex isn't effiecient.

json example :

```
           "created": "Fri Nov 27 11:12:43 +0000 2015",
            "text": "https://t.co/8r5dQ7zRYG #johnl3375 Kim Gi Jung",
            "source": "NOMOR1",
            "hashtags": [
                {
                    "text": "johnl3375",
                    "indices": [
                        24,
                        34
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "url": [
                {
                    "url": "https://t.co/8r5dQ7zRYG",
                    "expanded_url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aturkeuangan.nomor1#refid=johnl3375",
                    "display_url": "play.google.com/store/apps/det…",
                    "indices": [
                        0,
                        23
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

i want json like this

```
            "created": "Fri Nov 27 11:12:43 +0000 2015",
            "text": "https://t.co/8r5dQ7zRYG #johnl3375 Kim Gi Jung",
            "source": "NOMOR1",
            "hashtags": [
                {
                    "text": "johnl3375"
                }
            ],
            "url": [
                {
                    "url": "https://t.co/8r5dQ7zRYG",
                    "expanded_url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aturkeuangan.nomor1#refid=johnl3375",
                    "display_url": "play.google.com/store/apps/det…"
                }
            ]
```

what should my regex be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in ST3 using your JSON example: `[\s,]+"indices":[^]]+]`